# Why does this code abort when running for sizes [6, 10, 14, ...]

Tags: c++, sigabrt, sieve-of-eratosthenes

This is some code I wrote for implementing [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>

int allPrimes (unsigned long n) {
    std::vector<int> track (n, 0);
    int index = 2;
    int m = sqrt(n);
    while(index < n) {
        if (track[index] == 0) {
            std::cout << index << std::endl;
            int mul = 1;
            while ((index <= m) && (n >= (index * ++mul))) {
                track[index * mul] = 1;
            }
        }
        index++;
    }
}

int main() {
    int num;
    std::cin >> num;
    allPrimes(num);
}
```

Strangely, whenever `num` is in the series 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, ... the code aborts with the folloiwng stack while deallocating memory (runs okay for other `n`):

```
raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
__libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
malloc_printerr () from /lib64/libc.so.6
_int_free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate
std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_deallocate
std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::~_Vector_base
std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector
allPrimes (n=6) at allprimes.cpp:20
main () at allprimes.cpp:26
```

But I do not see the bug, or the logic behind these numbers spaced by 4. What is the bug here?

Comment: you could [test your solution against this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#C.2B.2B)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the abort with the code posted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
while(index <= n) {
    if (track[index] == 0) {
```

you allow `index` to run up to `n`, which is out of bounds. You need `n-1`, or `while (index < n)`. There are other such indexing errors in the code, all of which lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Fixed, but this is not the source of the errors I reported above, just checked.

Comment: There is a second error of the same kind, further down: `n >= ...` should be `n > ...`

Comment: Thanks, really silly errors, any idea why I always got errors spaced by 4 places? I kind of stopped debugging my code when I saw that pattern thinking it is something related to memory alignment.

Comment: @Lazer once there is undefined behaviour, I stop trying to make sense of the output, since anything could happen and there is little to learn.